# Spring MVC, Hibernate 3 and @Valid Problem

Tags: hibernate, validation, spring-mvc, annotations

I have a Spring MVC with JDBC that uses @Valid annotations and it all works very nicely, including the validation.

Now I have created a similar webapp that uses **Hibernate** (instead of JDBC) and it also works nicely so far.

I decided to 'bolt in' validation before continuing with more domains etc.

So I added **@Valid** to the save process in the Controller as so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/productgroup/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateProductGroup(**@Valid** ProductGroup productGroup, BindingResult bindingResult)
```

That is the **only** change that I make and now it crashes with:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Persistence.getPersistenceUtil()Ljavax/persistence/PersistenceUtil;
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.isReachable(SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:764)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForRedefinedDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:119)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:86)
```

I am using:
        
            org.hibernate
            hibernate-validator
            4.0.2.GA
            jar
        
        
            javax.validation
            validation-api
            1.0.0.GA

I have tried @NotEmpty on both the ProductGroup's productGroupName field and its Getter.

Any ideas?

I really never expected any problems here as I had no problems getting validation to work in my JDBC version...

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate Validator has an optional dependency on JPA, but when JPA is present in the classpath, Hibernate Validator 4 requires it to be JPA 2.0. In your case you have JPA 1.0 in the classpath.

In other words, Hibernate Validator 4 is compatible with Hibernate 3.5 or above. For older version of Hibernate see [Hibernate Compatibility Matrix](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCompatibilityMatrix).

Comment: Thanks for the swift response, it's really appreciated. I'm new to Spring and Hibernate so please bear with me. This webapp is just my way of learning, so I can change anything if necessary. The only other Hibernate jar I have specified is hibernate-entitymanager 3.3.2.GA which has dependencies. I'm a bit confused as to which version of Hibernate I should use. Any advice on the best setup for me to proceed?

Comment: @Lyndon: If you have no restrictions on Hibernate version, use the latest one, which is 3.6.1-Final.

Comment: @axtavt: I got hibernate-entitymanager 3.5.5-Final (before I read your reply) and put it in my pom.xml. But now I cannot even get a request to my controller! I just get 'The requested resource (/Product/productgroups.html) is not available.' On start-up I get lots of INFO statements for org.hibernate coming out, one of which is: INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found. Is there a new way to set Hibernate up? I can see many INFO lines like this too: INFO : ...DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/productgroups/] onto handler 'productGroupController'

Comment: @axtavt: I tried to get the 3.6.1-Final working but I kept getting this: [WARN] The POM for org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.1-Final is missing, no dependency information available   Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.1-Final:compile   Not sure what to do about that...

Comment: @axtavt: Changed back to hibernate-core 3.5.5-Final but now I get: [WARN] The POM for org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.4.RELEASE is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details    Did I say this was frustrating?  Anyway, I don't want to be a pain, I just wanted you to know that I HAVE been trying to solve this myself...  Any ideas?

Comment: @Lyndon: Perhaps it's caused by the fact that newer versions of Hibernate are not published in Maven Central repository. To access them via Maven, you need to configure Jboss repository, see http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Users.

Comment: @axtavt: Thanks again. But I did have an entry in pom.xml for <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url> and I have the jars but it came up with something about :compile missing.  Anyway, enough time spent on that. I have validation working now with hibernate-entitymanager and hibernate-core both set to 3.5.1-Final... So, mission accomplished. I have a spring mvc webapp with hibernate one-to-many relationship all working with validation! I have to say that I am very impressed with this set up, very lean on code... And thanks again for your help.

Comment: Regarding the compatibility I found the following comment on [HibernateCompatibilityMatrix](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCompatibilityMatrix): "Hibernate Validator 4.x is a separate code base for JSR 303. Hibernate 3.x is coded to use the Hibernate Validator 3.x code, and it will look for org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator which doesn't exist in Validator 4.x, so even if validator 4.x is in the classpath, hibernate 3.x will not try to use it."